# Control for presenting workflow

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I write an application in asp.net and I have something like state machine which can be modified by user (nodes, paths and directions of paths).

Is there any nice controll I can use to display this data ?

Just display, there is no need to do anything with it

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using Syncfusion Diagram for WinForms for such a thing.
They have an ASP.NET version also http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/aspnet/Diagram